# Criteria to decide whether a subset of the boundary complex of a polyhedron is a manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, polyhedra, combinatorial-topology

Let $\mathcal{P} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex polyhedron. Let $K$ be a subset of the boundary complex of $\mathcal{P}$. (Perhaps $K$ could be defined in terms of a system of linear inequalities.)

Is there a criterion (or a set of criteria) to tell whether $K$ is homeomorphic to a manifold? (Purity? Shellability? Something else?)

References?

Comment: Some references can be found at this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71400/when-are-finite-simplicial-complexes-smooth-manifolds

Comment: In fact, Mark's reference completely addresses this question. That question asks about finite simplicial complexes, but notice that a finite simplicial complex on $N$ vertices can always be realized as a subcomplex of the boundary of the $N-1$ dimensional simplex.